# Creating a Badge-less Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

According to the docs I have made an Google Chrome Extension that I would describe as a "browser action" because it is present on all pages. However, my extension doesn't require any interaction so having a badge next to the omnibox is pretty wasteful. I have installed extensions that do not appear anywhere (except maybe in the context menu). How is that done and is that best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having page action or browser action icons is totally optional if you don't have any popup attached to them, so just remove the whole `browser_action` section from your manifest file.